# How to config dataflow Pipeline to use a Shared VPC?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I know we have configuration arguments where you can specify network and subnets, I tried doing that but with a Shared VPC network, it gives me this error.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of subnetworks in Cloud Dataflow require to specify the subnetwork parameter when running the pipeline; However, in the case of subnetwork that are located in a Shared VPC network, it is required to use the **complete URL** based on the following format:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<HOST_PROJECT>/regions/<REGION>/subnetworks/<SUBNETWORK>
```

Additionally, verify you are adding the project's Dataflow service account into the Shared VPC's project IAM table and give it the **"Compute Network User"** role permission in order to ensure that the service has the required access scope.

You can take a look on the [Subnetwork parameter](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-networks#subnetwork_parameter) official Google's documentation which contains detailed information about this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to include the Project ID in the `--subnetwork` option:

```
/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/regions/<REGION>/subnetworks/<SUBNETWORK>
```

and give to the [Dataflow Service account](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/security-and-permissions#cloud-dataflow-service-account) the [Network User role](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#network_user_role) in the host project, which is what I suspect is going on according to the error message.